# Is it possible to initialize a std::map with n keys, where n is predefined?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I wonder if it is possible to initialize a `std::map` with `n` key:value elements in it, where `n` is predefined (something similar to array initialization: `array[n]`).

I am not aware that such a constructor exists for `std::map` but I thought I could ask just in case.

Alternately what one could do is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
   int n = 5;
   std::map<int,double> randomMap;

   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
       randomMap.insert({i,0.9});
   }

   for(auto j: randomMap)
   {
       std::cout<<"key: " << j.first <<"\tvalue: " << j.second << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initializer list constructor

Comment: If you're looking for something like `std::map<int, double> randomMap(5, 0.9);`, that doesn't exist.

Comment: @black What would you expect the keys to be for each of the elements for such a constructor? What if the key is some user-defined class and not just a numeric primitive?

Comment: @black You can also [check a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) and see that there is no such constructor specified by the standard.

Comment: @CoryKramer Yes, you're definitely right. I'd read it as if there were curly braces around it which would make it totally ok.

Answer (score 11):

Sure, you can use an initializer list, for example

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, double> randomMap {{0, 1.5}, {3, 2.7}, {9, 1.9}};
    for (auto const& element : randomMap)
    {
        std::cout << "key: " << element.first << " value: " << element.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Output](http://cpp.sh/3ody)

```
key: 0 value: 1.5
key: 3 value: 2.7
key: 9 value: 1.9
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that's available since C++11.

Comment: Sure, but the OP is already using `auto` so it is fair to assume they are already using a compiler with C++11 available. It is also the year 2015, I would hope most people are at least using C++11, or if they are not, they should specifically mention it in their question.